# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression When Return HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want Delete row with jquery ajax , in my view i call js function for  ajax controller/action

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="markup2('@Url.Action("ChannelDelete", "MyInfo", new {area = ""})');" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Delete</a>
```

```js
function markup2(e) {
  $(function() {
    $("#LoadPages").empty();
    $("#LoadPages").html('<div style="padding: 20px 15px"><div class="row"><div class="center-block col-md-1" style="float: none;"><img src="/Upload/pageLoader.gif" alt="loading..." /></div></div></div>');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: e
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("#LoadPages").load(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
}
```

The above function it's ok too , get url and send AJAX `POST` and get data;
when return data (html) and Inserting into the `$("#LoadPages")` element (`("#LoadPages").load(data)`)

get me an error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>
> ```
> <h2>my channels</h2>
>     <table class="table">
>         <tr>
>             <th>
>                 channel name
>             </th>
>             <th>
>                 name
>             </th>
>             <th>
>                 UserSelectedChannelJoinDate
>             </th>
>             <th></th>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
> ```

I don't know why get error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should really use unobtrusive event handlers instead of outdated `on*` event attributes.

Secondly, your issue is due to the use of `load()`. That method is intended to receive a URL to make an AJAX request which returns HTML, which is then set as the content of the specified element. However your code is giving a HTML string instead of a URL, hence the error.

To fix this, use `html()` instead of `load()`:

```
<a href="#" data-action="@Url.Action("ChannelDelete", "MyInfo", new {area = "" })" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#LoadPages").html('<div style="padding: 20px 15px"><div class="row"><div class="center-block col-md-1" style="float: none;"><img src="/Upload/pageLoader.gif" alt="loading..." /></div></div></div>');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).data('action')
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("#LoadPages").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

I would also strongly suggest you use an external stylesheet instead of the `style` attribute in your HTML.

Comment: How to add parameter to on* handler ?